# How to Amazon S3 pre-signed URL from android app without exposing Amazon Web Services credentials

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-s3, android-security

In my android app, I used Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs to display images in the app using the below code

```
var preSignedUrl = ""
        val s3Client: AmazonS3Client?
        val credentials: BasicAWSCredentials?
        credentials = BasicAWSCredentials(BuildConfig.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, BuildConfig.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
        s3Client = AmazonS3Client(credentials)

        try {
            val s3URI = AmazonS3URI(imgUrl)

            // Set the pre signed URL to expire after one day.
            val expiration = Date()
            var expTimeMillis: Long = Instant.now().toEpochMilli()
            expTimeMillis += (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7).toLong()
            expiration.time = expTimeMillis

            val generateSignedUrlRequest = GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(s3URI.bucket, s3URI.key)
                .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                .withExpiration(expiration)
            val url: URL = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generateSignedUrlRequest)
            preSignedUrl = url.toString()
            Logger().logInfo("AWS", "getImagePreSignedUrl $preSignedUrl")
        }catch (illEx: IllegalArgumentException){
            Logger().logInfo("AWS", "getImagePreSignedUrl err ${illEx.message.toString()}")
        }

        return preSignedUrl
```

But after releasing the app to google play it gives me the below warning

```
Your app(s) expose Amazon Web Services credentials.
```

Please advise me on how to achieve this in the app with or without storing AWS key and secret in the app?

Comment: What AWS SDK are you using to create a Native Android app. Looks like you are writing Kotlin code and using the AWS SDK for Java V1

Comment: I'm using these
`implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.25.0'
    implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.25.0@aar') { transitive = true }
    implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.25.0@aar') { transitive = true }`

Comment: Generally one doesn't create the presigned URL on device.  You create an endpoint in something like Lambda with some sort of user validation that can hand the presigned URL back to the application for it to use.

Answer (score 0):

A native Android app cannot use most of the ways that other apps can use to read creds. For example, a Native Android app cannot  load credentials from the [default] credentials profile in the shared credentials and config files ( that can easily be done using  an app like a Java Desktop Swing app).

Using a **StaticCredentialsProvider** is a reasonable way to solve it. This does mean that you have to specify your creds in the code when using this provider.

Comment: How does using StaticCredentialsProvider  prevent putting the credentials in the app?

Comment: It does not - my point is I cannot see a way around that given most other ways to read creds do not work from a Native Android app. Also, keep your eye on this thread over the next few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a crude idea.

You will need, API Gateway, AWS Lambda and SSM Parameter Store/Secrets Manager.

1. Create an API Gateway. Secure incoming requests by providing API Keys for your Android App.
2. Trigger a Lambda function to retrieve Credential stored in Secrets Manager or Parameter Store.
3. Encrypt the data using a private key available to your application.
4. Send the encrypted Secret and Access Key in the response.
5. Decrypt the data on your application.

This is technically a burden and you should do it once when your application initiates and then store the credentials in Shared Preferences and stop the retrieval until you have some values in preferences.

Or it is up to you how you want to manage it.

Comment: Or probably use Cloudfront.